# React router does not render starting page component properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have built test app using react and firebase and deployed it to Github Pages. When on localhost everything works fine, but when deployed for some reason the default page (starting one) does not render the component on that page. Here is my code which lies in the stateless functional component App.js. Just in case :
( routes.LANDING ="/" ).

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <React.Fragment>
     <Navigation />
     <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={Landing} />
     <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
     <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={SignIn} />
     <Route exact path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForget} />
     <Route exact path={routes.HOME} component={Home} />
     <Route exact path={routes.ACCOUNT} component={Account} />
     </React.Fragment>
   </BrowserRouter>
```

As far as I can understand with little experience with react-router, my https://d-ivashchuk.github.io/firebaseApp/ 
shall render Landing component. Instead I get nothing, otherwise all links and routes are working as expected.

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with setting up the `router`; however, isn't there an `index` property that specifies the default `Route` to use if no path is supplied? `<Route index />`

Comment: Well,technically there is no default route, as I understand it. When running locally localhost:3000/ serves as a default page and renders {Landing/}, I am expecting the same behavior from GitHub pages but ../firebaseApp/ should serve landing component in this case, however it’s not working

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? If so, please provide them if you are encountering any. If you are hosting the app publicly on github pages you can also provide a link I believe.

Comment: @DimitryIvashchuk Ultimately, it sounds like the `Landing` page is your index page. Index page is the page to go to if no page is specified. `site/` really means `site/index.html`. `.html` can be replaced with what ever files you are using, for example, `.php` for php files.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen Sorry,my bad, I supplied link to github repo,while I thought that I supplied it for gh Pages,will fix that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue lies with the router's relative path. Because your single page webapp is hosted on /firebaseApp/ loading https://d-ivashchuk.github.io/firebaseApp/ will never show the components that are supposed to display on '/'. You can change it to '/firebaseApp/' but, it will break your local version of the app. There is a create-react-app thread on this exact issue:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765

> To make react-router render the page which has '/' path in the
>   development mode, the route for that component shall utilize the
>   environment variables and would look like this `<Route
>   path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'}>` when deployed to GH pages.

For the record firebase, has its own website hosting service that you can use that should work with react-router. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: Hey Michael, your link to create-react-app issues was very helpful. Would you mind posting an definitive answer which should look something like this: To make react-router render the page which has '/' path in the development mode, the route for that component shall utilize the environment variables and would look like this <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'}> when deployed to GH pages. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I have not tried it myself but, i'll edit the answer with your recommendation assuming it worked for you.

Comment: Everything worked fine, but I used <Switch> from react-router-dom to make it work both locally and when deployed. I basically included code from above comment with env variable and the original one with path=‘/‘ and it works as expected! Thanks!